# Auto increment primary key and reseed every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

What is the best solution to create SQL table which has a composite primary key.

- First column of the primary key is `ID` {`int`}.
- Second column of the primary key is `YearMonth` {`string` like yyyyMM ex. 201409 } which is current month.

that can reseed an ID to 1 every month

And I actually need the running ID like

```
"201409-00001"  
"201409-00002"   
"201409-00003"  
.  
.  
"201410-00001"   
"201410-00002"   
.  
.   
"201411-00001"
```

Comment: Just use a datetime and generate the result in your program logic

Comment: You could use a trigger (instead of trigger) für the insert event and implement the logic for your primary key there.

Comment: You ***CANNOT*** have two primary keys in any table. That's just plain impossible.

Comment: @marc_s I mean Composite Primary Key

Comment: I think what you really need is `YearMonth as LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112),6) + '-' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',5) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),ID),5)` with ID which is reset at every start of month

Comment: @ughai Yes that is the formation that i need but, what is the solution that Microsoft Sql-Server provided to my need?

Comment: @ZenithS - do you need this for display purposes?

Comment: Is this a smart design choice? Personally, I could think of no situation where I wouldn't rather use a normal incrementing PK for the table (or guid) and, if needed, have another column (_customId_ or similar) that would be populated through a trigger in a manner like you describe. Mostly curious as to why you'd want such a complex PK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I try using the concept of Mr. @ughai 
and I using the query like below to keep the values on another column for represent the ID with month relatively.

```
select LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YearMonth,112),6) + '-' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',4) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YearMonth,112),6) ORDER BY ID)),5)  from TestTable
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the question and your comments, it seems that you need to display the a row identifier in the format `201411-00001`. This does not need to be your actual primary key. What I would recommend is that you do something like this.

create your table with `ID` which is Identity. Add another column `YearMonth CHAR(6)` column which stores `YYYYMM` or if you already have a column which stores the date as `date/datetime`, use that. In your `SELECTs` you would do something like this

```
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YearMonth,112),6) + '-' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',5) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DateCol, ORDER BY ID),5)
```

You would alternately have a trigger which updates a new `INT` column `monthlyID` based on the `MAX(monthlyID) + 1` for the month.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try concatenating them and creating a new column to make it the primary key?

Don't know if there is a simpler method,but this should work:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'-',ID) 
FROM <TABLE NAME>;
```

Comment: And how can I reseed an ID every month ?

Comment: have you understood the question properly @deepika

Answer (score 0):

1. Create sequence start at 1 and concat it to your 'year,month'
2. Create job at every 1st of month and restart the sequence

Comment: OP doesn't want the day of the date at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

and this:

```
ALTER TABLE foobar_data MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '201409';
```

and run this query via some method every month ;)